# azure stream analytics group multiple inputs to one output

Tags: t-sql, azure, group-by, azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

i am working with azure stream analytics and want to group multiple inputs with same time to only one output.
[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4dzq.png)

how can i modify my code that it prints for example in first line:

```
{"HO","KSPF","07","03","#300","46091240","2017-05-31T10:17:34:4430000Z"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably aggregate using [Collect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt732314.aspx) over very small tumbling window, like 1 millisecond. And then write [JavaScript UDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-functions) to create one event result from the array accumulated by Collect aggregate.